# How do I set a data cap in a SUMIF function?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I want to create a single formula that combines the two formulas together:
`=IF(E1>500,500,E1)`
and
`=SUMIF(A1:A10,"Y",E1:E10)`

Basically, I want to sum items from columns E1 to E10 when the value of a row in column A is equal to "Y".

I want to set a data cap wherein if one of the values to be added is greater than 500 (for example: 589), then the formula will read add the cell value as 500 instead of 589.
If the value is 500 or less, we are adding the value as is.

How do I this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may follow different approaches here:

1. use an array formula:
   `=SUM((A1:A10="y")*IF(E1:E10>500,500,E1:E10))`
   this is an array formula, so after typing it you need to finish by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER
2. split your task and cover different scenarios with different functions:
   `=SUMIFS(E1:E10,A1:A10,"y",E1:E10,"<500")+COUNTIFS(A1:A10,"y",E1:E10,">=500")*500`
   Here `SUMIFS` calculates only sum of entries below 500, and `COUNTIFS` counts entries above 500

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! This is exactly what I need :)